# I need to identify all users with SIDhistory for a migration

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a powershell script together to go through all users in our domain and find if they have a SIDhistory located in the SIDhistory attribute or not.  I then need to export this list of users to a csv as i will need to delete all the accounts without a SIDhistory.  I'm still learning powershell but this is what I have so far to find individual user's sidhistory. ( export CSV portion isn't working correctly )

dsquery * -Filter "(samaccountname=USERID)" -Attr samAccountName ObjectSID sidHistory | export-csv -path C:\Desktop\insertcsv.csv -notypeinformation

Thank you any help you can provide, I really appreciate it.

tl;dr - I need to pull all users with an empty SIDhistory attribute to a csv

Comment: How about something like `get-aduser -filter {!(SIDhistory = *)} -prop ObjectSID,sidHistory|Select SamAccountName,ObjectSID,sidHistory|ExportCsv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\NoSIDHistory.csv -notype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy!

```
Get-aduser -filter * -properties sidhistory | Where sidhistory
```

This will first return all users, then instruct PowerShell to also return the `sidhistory` property if it exists. Then we filter using `Where-Object` to only return the accounts which have that property.